# how to plot specific US counties using their FIP with a gradient effect on single map

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, usmap

I have dataframe below:

```
mydf <- data.frame(FIP=c(1017,1059,1061,1133,5103,12129,13123,12129), 
val=c(100,100,225,400,180,278,180,321))
```

I want to shade US counties on one single map whose FIPs are in FIP colum, but I am stuck at is how to shade these specific counties such that something like a heat map appears. the counties higher pop are more red and counties with lower pop are more blue (like typical gradient of heat map).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(usmap)
library(grDevices)


dt <- countypop %>%
    dplyr::mutate(selected = factor(ifelse(fips %in% stringr::str_pad(mydf$FIP, 5, pad = "0"), 
"1", 
"0")))

usmap::plot_usmap(data = dt, values = "selected", color = "grey") +
    ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c(rainbow(8))
```

I can shade specific counties (although if all are going to be shaded with color!) but I want a gradient effect here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. As far as I get it you want to make a map where only the counties present in your dataframe df get colored according to the `val`.

To this end you could join `mydf` to `countypop`. Doing so will automatically assign `NA` to the `val` column of non-selected counties. To color by `val` you have to set the `values` argument equal to `"val"` in `usmap::plot_usmap`. To get a gradient of values use `ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient` where you could set the color used for `NA` via the `na.value` argument, e.g. in the code below I make use of `na.value = "transparent"`:

```r
mydf <- data.frame(
  FIP = c(1017, 1059, 1061, 1133, 5103, 12129, 13123, 12129),
  val = c(100, 100, 225, 400, 180, 278, 180, 321)
)

library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

mydf <- mutate(mydf, FIP = stringr::str_pad(FIP, 5, pad = "0"))

dt <- countypop %>%
  left_join(mydf, by = c("fips" = "FIP"))

plot_usmap(data = dt, values = "val", color = "grey", size = .25) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", na.value = "transparent")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I am working on your code to see if I can get my desired result from it. I edited mydf to avoid further confusion. I do not want the counties to be shaded gradiently based on 2015_population. I want them to be gradiently shaded according to val column values.

Comment: I see. This is not a big deal and in some sense even simpler. To this end you could go on with a `left_join`. See my edit. Best S.